# Laravel 5 Eloquent count many to many relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have table `user` and `roles` with many to many relationships using pivot table `role_user` table.

I'm using `belongstomany` relationships on my model

How do I make an eloquent query to count how many user has role `admin` and `staff`

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

add this to `Role.php` model

```
public function userCount() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
        ->selectRaw('count(role_user.user_id) as total_user')
        ->groupBy('role_id');
}
```

and this

```
public function getUserCountAttribute()
    {
        if ( ! array_key_exists('userCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('customerCount');

        $related = $this->getRelation('userCount')->first();

        return ($related) ? $related->total_user : 0;
    }
```

after that, to make an eloquent query...

```
$roleUsers = Role::with('userCount')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```